# Bootstrap Tabs change parent background Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to figure out a more elegant solution. But my jquery skills are limited as of now.

I'd imagine there is a better way to achieve the function below. 
In few words. I am trying to change the background of the parent on click.

Right now, i just add a class and remove other possible classes from the other buttons.

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div class="panel panel-widget widget-latest-posts">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="widget-title">Ebenfalls lesenswert</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button type="button" id="btn-popular-posts" class="btn btn-popular-posts" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-fire"></i>
                                    <span class="hidden-xs">Beliebt</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button type="button" id="btn-latest-posts" class="btn btn-latest-posts" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                    <span class="hidden-xs">Neu</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button type="button" id="btn-popular-comments" class="btn btn-popular-comments" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>
                                    <span class="hidden-xs">Aktiv</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.bpp-toggled {
    background: orange !important;
}
.blp-toggled {
    background: lime !important;
}
.bpc-toggled {
    background: purple !important;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#btn-popular-posts").click(function() {

    $('.widget-latest-posts').addClass('bpp-toggled');
    $('.widget-latest-posts').removeClass('blp-toggled');
    $('.widget-latest-posts').removeClass('bpc-toggled');
});

$("#btn-latest-posts").click(function() {

    $('.widget-latest-posts').addClass('blp-toggled');
    $('.widget-latest-posts').removeClass('bpp-toggled');
    $('.widget-latest-posts').removeClass('bpc-toggled');
});

$("#btn-popular-comments").click(function() {

    $('.widget-latest-posts').addClass('bpc-toggled');
    $('.widget-latest-posts').removeClass('blp-toggled');
    $('.widget-latest-posts').removeClass('bpp-toggled');
});
```

Can you please help me up with a better more elegant solution or maybe keyword I could do some researches on. Because right now, it is very hard to maintain given i'll add few more buttons.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: I know about toggleClass. But that didnt work out in that case. Because it just removed the class on 2nd click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply uses data attributes to hold the class in the button itself.  You can also use a function within the removeClass with a regular expression to remove the initial toggled class before applying the new one.

In the future when you add buttons, you'll only need to ensure the button has the proper data-target-class attribute and the proper class set up in your css.  No changes to the javascript would be necessary as long as you followed consistent naming conventions.

```js
$("button[data-toggle='tab']").click(function() {
    $('.widget-latest-posts').removeClass(function (index, className) {
      return (className.match (/([a-z]{3,3})-toggled/g) || []).join(' ');
    }
  );
  $('.widget-latest-posts').addClass($(this).attr("data-toggled-class"));
});
```

```css
.bpp-toggled {
    background: orange !important;
}
.blp-toggled {
    background: lime !important;
}
.bpc-toggled {
    background: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-widget widget-latest-posts">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="widget-title">Ebenfalls lesenswert</h3>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
<div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" id="btn-popular-posts" class="btn btn-popular-posts" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" data-toggled-class="bpp-toggled"><i class="fa fa-fire"></i>
            <span class="hidden-xs">Beliebt</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" id="btn-latest-posts" class="btn btn-latest-posts" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" data-toggled-class="blp-toggled"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
            <span class="hidden-xs">Neu</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" id="btn-popular-comments" class="btn btn-popular-comments" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" data-toggled-class="bpc-toggled"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>
            <span class="hidden-xs">Aktiv</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```