# Change parent or ancestor element color when hovered over a link

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website where I want to change the color of the whole navigation bar when I hover over a link that is a child or descendants of that navigation bar.

```css
.containernav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
/*home*/
#home {
  color: white;
}
#home:hover {
  background-color: white;
}



/*playstation*/
#playstation {
  color: white;
}
#playstation:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}



/*xbox*/
#xbox {
  color: white;
}
#xbox:hover{
  background-color: green;
}



/*pcgaming*/
#pcgaming {
  color: white;
}
#pcgaming:hover {
  background-color: #FFBA00;
}




 nav > ul {
   list-style: none;
 }

nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="containernav" id="a">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="playstation" href="playstation.html">Playstation</a></li>
        <li><a id="xbox" href="xbox.html">XBox</a></li>
        <li><a id="pcgaming" href="pcgaming.html">PC-Gaming</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My current implementation only changes the color of the link it self, but not the container with the css style class **containernav**. What need to be changed in order to change the background color of that container?

Comment: Refer the below link and change it as your requirement, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768467/bootstrap-tabs-change-parent-background-jquery

Answer (score 1):

This is not achievable with css. There are several topics regarding this matter - some of them demands for a :parent selector, some of them saing that this will be a huge performance issue. 
However you can do this with javascript if this is an option for you.
Here is a quick example with Jquery:

```
$("#child").hover(function(){
     $(this).parent().css("bakground,"red");
     //This should be ajusted according your needs
     // Can be achieved with data attribute, custom class etc..
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#home").hover(
    function() {
      $(".containernav").addClass("white-bg");
    }, function() {
      $(".containernav").removeClass("white-bg");
    }
  );

  $("#playstation").hover(
    function() {
      $(".containernav").addClass("blue-bg");
    }, function() {
      $(".containernav").removeClass("blue-bg");
    }
  );

 // and so on..

});
```

CSS

```
.white-bg {background-color:white;}
.blue-bg {background-color:blue;}

// and so on
```